# VS Code Python Intellisense and pylint not working properly

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I just installed VS Code on my Macbook, and set out to test a few of its features. I installed the Python extension, pylint, selected the Python interpreter...followed the docs to the letter. Oddly, the Intellisense feature doesn't seem to be working, and pylint looks a bit odd. I expect squiggly red error lines, and a lightbulb next to the line with np.array suggesting that I import numpy. Instead I have double red underlines and no lightbulb. See image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xn9oo.png). It also only lints when I save the file. The error when I hover the np line is "undefined variable np." So it seems like it's linting, but not doing intellisense.

Similarly, I don't have any code snippets; when I type if and then ^-Space for the drop-down, there aren't any snippets.

I have anaconda installed, but it doesn't make any difference which Python interpreter I use.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Settings.json file:

```
{
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3" }
```

VS Code Info:

```
Version: 1.52.1
Commit: ea3859d4ba2f3e577a159bc91e3074c5d85c0523
Date: 2020-12-16T16:30:02.420Z (1 mo ago)
Electron: 9.3.5
Chrome: 83.0.4103.122
Node.js: 12.14.1
V8: 8.3.110.13-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 19.6.0
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the information you provided, I reproduced this problem, please refer to the following method:

1. The reason for the double horizontal line instead of the wavy line shown in the code is the use of color themes.
   (Change theme: `F1`, `Preferences: Color Theme`)
2. Please make sure that the module "pylint" has been installed in your currently selected Python environment. (Install: `pip install pylint`; check: `pip show pylint`)

before:

[image]

after:

[image]

Comment: Thanks -- you're right about the theme. But the pylint issue isn't solved. pip show pylint gives

Name: pylint
Version: 2.5.3
Summary: python code static checker
Home-page: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint
Author: Python Code Quality Authority
Author-email: code-quality@python.org
License: GPL
Location: /Users/jonahpearl/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: mccabe, isort, astroid, toml
Required-by: spyder

Comment: I've tried downgrading the Python extension as well with no change.

Comment: @JP101 -Please make sure that the Python environment (bottom left corner of VS Code) you select in VS Code is the same as the location where the module "pylint" exists (anaconda3/lib/python3.8).

Comment: Thanks -- the interpreter is Python 3.8 in ~/opt/anaconda3/bin/python, pylint is in ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages.

Installing npm allowed pylint to start working at all, but now I'm dealing with the known issue that pylint doesn't lint in real time, so I switched to the Microsoft Python language server...what a mess. Plus intellisense still doesn't suggest importing numpy...it asks if I want to extract a method!! Rip.

Comment: @JP101  -1. When testing, the python language service I use is also "Microsoft". Pylint as a python code analysis tool, sometimes it takes a little time, but basically it can work well. 2. For quick fix (import suggestion), usually, it is better recognized after using this import, otherwise it will think that this is the variable name you defined. The quick fix function provides us with suggestions and cannot be used as our editing code Completely dependent.

Comment: @JP101 -How are things going? Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. If my answer solves the problem, please [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as an answer to help others who have the same problem.